# Names of Locations on Google Map

Tags: google-maps

I am curious to know if Google added the names of buildings on Google Map by default. I notice that not all the buildings are named. Does anyone know the criteria for this? Is there a way to add the names ourselves?

Thanks!

BK

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to add new places...Please refer to the google map support (there's even a video)

> http://support.google.com/maps/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=144367

Comment: he needs the reputation more than i do tick this one!

Answer (score 0):

You can list yourself by listing yourself in [Google Places](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/). Then you get a pin number sent to your address and your building is named.

Comment: please accept an answer by putting a green tick beside it. YOu will see the tick appear when you hover beside the answer. Click it.